# Insert values of dynamically created textboxes into sqlserver and display in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, dynamic, textbox

Hi I have a webform which contains both static and dynamic textboxes. I have written a code to create unlimited dynamic textboxes (maximum used would be **31** but i am giving user flexibility) **but now I have to insert the values of dynamically created textboxes in database**

Suppose I fill some text in 1 textbox it automatically creates a next textbox ie., as soon as i enter 1 character in the 1st textbox it generate new text box, finally when i click submit I want all this data from  textboxes to store in database.

***It should create new fields/columns for every new textbox generated, but if it is within the maximum limit then it should insert the data within the columns previously created***. Any Solution?

Here is my code:
**WebForm1.aspx**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    getId = function ()
     {
        var id = 1;
        return function () 
        {
            id++;
        }
    }

    function CreateTextbox() 
    {
        var box = document.getElementById("divCreateTextbox");
        var curr = 'txt' + getId();
        var inp = document.createElement('input');
        inp.type = 'text';
        inp.name = 'textfield';
        inp.setAttribute("id", 'curr');
        inp.setAttribute("minlength", '1');
        box.appendChild(inp);
        inp.setAttribute('onkeyup', 'moveOnMin(this)');
        inp.setAttribute("textBoxAdded", "0");
        inp.focus();

    }

    function moveOnMin(s)
     {
         if (s.value.length == parseInt(s.getAttribute("minlength")) && s.getAttribute("textBoxAdded") == "0")
         {
            CreateTextbox();
            s.setAttribute("textBoxAdded", "1");
            s.focus();
        }
    }
```

```
        <div id="divCreateTextbox"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function ()
       {
            CreateTextbox()
       }
```

**WebForm1.aspx.cs**(Code to insert static textboxes text into sql)

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

     SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Tbl Return's Tracker]", connection);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);

                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            }
    }

    protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Tbl Return's Tracker] ([Company],[Date],[Month],[OrderReference],[Product],[Status],[ReturnLabel],[NumberOfLenses],[Shelf], [ReshipmentNumber],[Reason1],[Reason2],[ActionTaken],[ReturnHandledby])VALUES (@company,@date,@month,@orderreferencenumber,@product,@status,@returnlabel,@numberoflenses,@shelf,@reshipmentordernumber,@Reason1,@Reason2,@action,@name)", connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", DdlCompany.SelectedItem.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", LblMonth.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", LblDate.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderreferencenumber", TxtOrderReferenceNo.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product", DdlProduct.SelectedItem.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", DdlStatus.SelectedItem.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@returnlabel", DdlReturnLabel.SelectedValue);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numberoflenses", TxtNumberOfLenses.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shelf", DdlShelf.SelectedItem.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reshipmentordernumber", TxtReshipmentOrderNo.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason1", DdlReason1.SelectedItem.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason2", DdlReason2.SelectedItem.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@action", DdlAction.SelectedItem.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", DdlName.SelectedItem.Text);

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        GridView1.DataBind();         

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand u correctly...

You need to clean up your code. Make sure you have unique ID set for the controls. Your getid does not return ID - debug and check it out. Make the var id global and correct this code in your CreateTextBox Func

```
var box = document.getElementById("divCreateTextbox");
var curr = 'txt' + id++; // getId();
var inp = document.createElement('input');
inp.type = 'text';
inp.name = curr;  //'textfield';
inp.setAttribute("id", curr);
```

In your postback just loop thru your controls

```
 For Each txtBx As String In Request.Form
        If txtBx.StartsWith("txt") Then 
 Response.Write(txtBx & "=" & Request.Form(txtBx) & "<BR>")
 end if
    Next
```

is this what you need?

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for looking into it ! I actually wanted to insert the text from dynamic textboxes to database, is there any way i can do it at runtime ?

Comment: I have just edited my question, I hope its more clear than before.. Thanks !

Comment: Look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827175/entering-values-into-database-from-unlimited-dynamic-controls?lq=1 This should give you an idea on how to proceed.